# How can I deploy my shiny app as a package?

Tags: r, shiny, golem

I want to deploy my shiny application but as a package something like this:

```
library(mylibrary)

run_app()
```

How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Where do you want to deploy it ? What infrastructure ? Is your application a {golem} already ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're built your app using `{golem}`, you can do the following:

- deploy on CRAN, then build the app as a package (`devtools::build()`), then send the `tar.gz` to the CRAN
- deploy on RStudio products, then you can use one of the functions from `{golem}` to do that (`add_rstudioconnect_file()` for example)
- As a docker container, then you can build the `Dockerfile` using `golem::add_dockerfile()`

I'd suggest the following resource for more information: https://engineering-shiny.org/deploy-golem.html

Colin

Comment: One thing to discuss is that publishing to CRAN is not as easy as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to use `rsconnect` package/way to deploy the app.
Then you could use CRAN and/or public github packages.

https://rdrr.io/cran/rsconnect/man/rsconnectPackages.html

You should start with putting your package on public in github. Then install it locally with `devtools::install_github` which is important to create a proper DESCRIPTION file for `packrat` package. Now you could use the `rsconnect::deployApp` function or rsconnect button to deploy the app.